.Net SDK 9.0 will not Install on Windows 11
.Net SDK 9.0 will not Install on Windows 11. When I try to install the installation starts but gets stuck in about 25% of the way and never completes.

Are there any error messages? How long do you wait when you say "stuck"? Also how do you know its 25% of the way (out of curiousity). What are you seeing as far as progress?

I get no error messages. I know it goes about 25% far because of the green bar it shows during the "Installation Progress" screen. I have waited about 1 hour when I say "stuck" and nothing happens, the green bar just stays at about 25% of the way.

This is pretty rare I think. Make sure you have sufficient disk space and memory, shut down all other programs/applications, restart your computer, and keep trying. I'm not very good with logs but there probably are some somewhere you can try the event log or google to see if you can find any file-based installation logs for .Net installations. Try downloading a new install file too and verifying it after download ... just in case https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

I have more than enough memory and disk space. I downloaded  the sw from the link you sent and tried to install it for the nth time (as admin) and I still have exactly the same problem.

Does the .Net 8 sdk work? Any problems installing other things? How old is your computer?

No, .Net 8 SDK does not work either. My laptop is a brand new 2024 DELL i7 Core.

I fixed the issue. It was my ESET Antivirus. I inactivated it for 10 minutes while I tried to install the .NET 9 SDK and that resolved the issue.

Please Try following things.

Open run panel and hit following command and Delete all the files
%temp% , temp, prefetch and delete all the file
Download Latest SDK From the Microsoft site .Net SDK 9.0


Run SDK Installer As Run As Administrator


You solution did not work

I fixed the issue. It was my ESET Antivirus. I inactivated it for 10 minutes while I tried to install the .NET 9 SDK and that resolved the issue.
